# Slick "for/yield"-query doesn't compile with negative comparison

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, slick, slick-3.0

I ran into an odd problem with my `slick`-query:
[image]

As you can see, the function below is compiling although it's basically the same query but with a possitive comparison (I don't know if it's actually doing what it's supposed to do, though). When swapping the order of the `if` conditions, it tells me that `&&` cannot be resolved. I don't know if that's the case, but I guess the second `table query object`, in this case `contents`, doesn't seem to be finished yet. However, that begs the question why the second function/query is compiling properly.

Do you have an answer to this? Am I doing something wrong here?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `=!=` for inequality and `===` for equality in queries according to slick [docs](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.2.3/queries.html#expressions)

Answer (score 0):

I guess I've fixed the problem.

Instead of:

`if a.documentId === documentId && b.contentTypeId !== ContentType.PROCESS`

I needed to write:

`if a.documentId === documentId && !(b.contentTypeId === ContentType.PROCESS)`

Still a weird behavior I can't really explain, espacially since negative comparisons like `!==` are generally allowed in those `if`-statements